# how to make checkbox in uitableview with condition?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, custom-cell

I have two button when i click on btn1 `UITableview` display same as below image 1 and i click on btn2 `UIableView` display same as below image 2

I am using custom cell. I have done with table reload but it display "checkbox" in both `UITableview`.

```
  BOOL isChecked;
  isChecked = true;


    -(IBAction)btn1:(id)sender
     { 
        isChecked = true;
      [self.mytableview reload];
     } 
    -(IBAction)btn2:(id)sender
     { 
        isChecked = false;
      [self.mytableview reload];
     }
```

`cellRowAtIndexPath` method in:

```
  if(isChecked)
  {
    customcell.trLabel.text = [arr1 objectAtIndex : indexpath.row]
    [customcell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIstateselected];
     [customcell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIstateNormal];
     [customcell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  }
  else
  {
    customcell.trLabel.text = [arr2 objectAtIndex : indexpath.row]
    [customcell.buttton = NULL;
  }
```

difrent method

```
 -(void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender
  {
      sender.selected = !sender.selected;
  }
```

[image]image 1

[image]image 2

i  have done select all.

`didSelect` Method:

```
  DemoTableViewCell *cell;
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.tableview1 numberOfSections]; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < [self.tableview1 numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++) {
            NSUInteger ints[2] = {i,j};
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:ints length:2];
            cell = (DemoTableViewCell *)[self.tableview1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            //Here is your code

            UIButton *btn = cell.button;

            if( [[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"]])
            {
                [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                // other statements
            }
            else
            {
                [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            }
        }
    }
}
else
{

   cell = (DemoTableViewCell *)[self.tableview1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIButton *btn = cell.button;

    if( [[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"]])
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // other statements
    }
    else
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }


}
```

My question is:

1) select all option select all "checkbox" that is done but when i "uncheck" any item of them select all option also be "uncheck".
2) Not display "checbox" in image 2 `UITablevieCell`.
3) When i "uncheck" item3 and click again select all option deselect all "checkbox" except item3 and item3 is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to 2) Not display "checbox" in image 2 UITablevieCell

You need to create a different prototype cell with no checkbox. 
Then in `cellRowAtIndexPath` method use that cell if button 2 was clicked

---

For other questions, you need to store the state of each checkbox (in array or dictionary) . Then in `cellRowAtIndexPath` method depending on the state of checkbox in that row, tick or untick the checkbox of the cell

1) Have `NSMutableArray` in your ViewController where you would store all your checkboxes state (ticked or unticked).

2) In the method that is called when checkbox is ticked/unticked, update 1 or 0 in the array like:

```
- (void) actionCheckbox {
        self.mydata[indexPath.row] = 1;    // set 0 or 1
        [self.tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPath ...];  // Don't remember exact method name
}
```

3) In `cellRowAtIndexPath`,

```
 if(self.mydata[indexPath.row] == 1) {
     // tick checkbox for this row
 } else {
     // untick checkbox for this row
 }
```

Comment: i got it your first solution. but i didn't get another solution can you provide me any example or perfect hint @user427969

Comment: hi,, i have understand your answer but is giving me a warning or error. @user427969

Comment: i am getting warning int to id not conversation error.have you perfect solution please give me and same issue how to store selected index in did-select method  when i press select all checkbox all are checked and when i uncheck any of them select all option  not uncheck. or i am press again select all option except uncheck option is check and other are uncheck please provide me solution  @user427969

Comment: Sorry, I can't do your work. I can only guide you in the right direction.

Comment: In action of Select All button, iterate through entire self.mydata array and set everything to 1 and for Uncheck All button's action set everything to 0. Reload table after that.